# Sorting argv value by strcmp with a function

Tags: c

I want to do it with my own function (I know that qsort would probably be a better option).
Here's what I've done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void order(int count, char** strings);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("%s, ", argv[i]);
    }
    printf("\nAfter: \n");
    order(argc, argv);
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("%s, ", argv[i]);
    }

    getchar();  
    return 0;
}

void order(int count, char** strings)
{
    char temp[50] = { 0 };
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    for (x = 1; x < count - 1; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < count - x - 1; y++)
        {
            if (strcmp(strings[y], strings[y + 1]) > 1)
            {
                strcpy(temp, strings[y]);
                strcpy(strings[y], strings[y+1]);
                strcpy(strings[y+1], temp);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It doesn't change anything in the array, I would appreciate any kind of help, thanks!

Comment: how strcmp can help you in sorting????, for you all the inputs will be of different length???

Comment: @piyushjaiswal: The behavior of `strcmp` with strings of different lengths is well defined, consistent, and usually regarded as 'correct'.

Comment: what have you done so far to try and debug  this? e.g. print out a list of things which are swapped in the innermost loop.

Comment: @RadLexus true, that's why i wanted to confirm the same, as its never mentioned in the question, that inputs will be of different length :)

Comment: `strcpy(strings[y], strings[y+1]);` : They does not necessarily have the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the result of `strcmp` wrong. According to its `man` pages, it

> return an integer greater than, equal to, or less than **0**, if the string pointed to by s1 is greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by s2, respectively.

and so this line is wrong:

```
if (strcmp(strings[y], strings[y + 1]) > 1)
```

Compare against 0 to make it work.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe I forgot how strcmp works.